# Why the Accuracy Score is Zero in Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis

The training data contains around 20000 rows with headers: `id, sentiment, text`

I have mapped the sentiment as follow:

```
df.sentiment= df.sentiment.map({"Neutral": 1, "Negative":0, "Positive":2 })
```

After I have `clean`  and `text pre-processing`, I used `Logistic Regression` as follow:

```
XTR, XTST, YTR, YTST= train_test_split(df.text, df.sentiment, test_size =.2, random_state=100)
lg= LogisticRegression(max_iter=20000)
pp = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(),lg)
pg= {'logisticregression__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}
m= GridSearchCV(pipe, pg, cv=5)
m.fit(XTR,YTR)

pr= m.predict(XTST)
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy_score(YTST, pr):.2f}")
print(classification_report(YTST, pr))
```

The `Output` is as follow:

```
    Accuracy 0.59
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00       686
           1       0.59      1.00      0.74      2374
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00       940

    accuracy                           0.59      4000
   macro avg       0.20      0.33      0.25      4000
weighted avg       0.35      0.59      0.44      4000
```

Why I get `0.00` for both `Negative: 0` and `Positive: 2` ? any help please

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the logistic regression model is predicting every row as Neutral.

So Accuracy of Neutral  = 2374/4000 = 0.59

Accuracy of Positive = 0/4000 = 0

Accuracy of Negative = 0/4000 = 0

Moreover, you are taking out the predictions on X_train, while you have to do it on X_test

```
pr= m.predict(XTS)
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy_score(YTST, pr):.2f}")
print(classification_report(YTST, pr))
```

Comment: any help please on how to fix ?

Comment: by why it does do that? what is my mistake please ?

Comment: Try some other models because logistic regression is simply not able to predict the sentiment. Try tree-based models and see if that works for you.

Comment: When I used it on different dataset, it worked fine, but when I made higher dataset it did not work ? is there any relation? and if u can help fix I appreciate it. I thought the error is in `GridSearchCV` in parameter `pg which is param_grid`

Comment: Okay I found the issue. You have to change your code a bit.

pr= m.predict(XTS)
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy_score(YTST, pr):.2f}")
print(classification_report(YTST, pr))

Comment: Sorry brother, In my original code its XTST, just my mistake copying it here, can you please check again, cuz that what exactly I got only 0

Comment: Simply try this code - 
lg= LogisticRegression(max_iter=20000)
m.fit(XTR,YTR)
pr= m.predict(XTST)
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy_score(YTST, pr):.2f}")
print(classification_report(YTST, pr))

Comment: But it is the same code that I published ?? I did not see any changes in your code. and thanks in advance

Comment: No, I removed the GridSearchCV code from your code. Look closely.

Comment: but if u did that, i can not get the model `m=GridSearchCV (...)` and i can NOT run the `m.predict...`

Comment: My bad, change m.predict to lg.predict in the code I tried above.

Comment: same results, any way thank you brother. I will try to change other parameters maybe would help thanks again

Comment: No issues. The original answer to your question is that the model is predicting everything as Neutral, hence 0 accuracy score for negative and positive. The only things you can do is optimizing the logistic regression model or train a new model like tree-based models. Thanks